# How to change font for text objects?

Tags: text-object

Is there a way to select a typeface (I have 15,000 fonts) for a text object, or must I set type in AI and save as SVG, then import into Blender?

Comment: Do you mean how to add text at all, or just change the font of a text object?

Comment: I know how to add text, but it's always in Gill Sans. HOW do I find access to font list and change the face?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can change the font used for a text object under the *Object Data* properties panel.

[image]

Here you can specify different fonts for standard, bold, and italics; as well as various other typesetting parameters.  You can also define a set of objects as a custom font by naming them something like `fontName_a`, `fontName_b`, etc. and use `fontName_` as the *Object Font*.

---

In order to find fonts easily I have bookmarked my system's fonts folder (`C:\Windows\Fonts\` on Windows, `/Library/Fonts` on macOS) in Blender's file browser so I can quickly add new fonts.  *Note: as Chebhou explains [in his answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46943/5705) you can also set the default directory for when browsing for fonts in the user preferences.*

[image]

Note that as of Blender 2.76, you the file browser's thumbnail display mode now works for previewing fonts.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I finally found a tutorial on YouTube. As a Blender noob, I'm spoiled by font management software on Mac (FontAgentPro). As Blender doesn't have system-level font access, I need to use FontAgentPro to find the fonts I want, locate them on the system drive, and manually load each one into Blender. It's tedious, but at least now I know it's possible. Thanks for the help.  :+)

Comment: @DrStrik9  No problem!  I guess macs handle fonts differently than Windows, on Windows it's pretty easy since they're all in one system folder.  (If this answer has sufficiently solved your problem you can mark it as [accepted](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark under the voting buttons.)

Comment: @PGmath if you set the fonts directory you don't need to do that at all

Comment: @Chebhou  What do you mean?

Comment: see step 1 in my answer.  so when you browse for fonts it will automatically open that directory

Comment: Blender is a powerful tool and does a wonderful job of hiding obvious features behind layers of complexity. That's unfortunate, as that creates a huge barrier to the casual or beginning user.

Comment: @EricJ. I really don't see how *Object Properties* > *Font* is "hiding behind layers of complexity", it is after all a property of the font object.

Comment: And it's probably totally obvious to someone who uses Blender regularly because you're used to its UI paradigm. Blender is the only software I have ever come across where I have to routinely google to discover how to perform basic functions.

Comment: @EricJ. Have you every used any commercial CG software?  IMO Max is *way* worse than Blender in that respect.  And when you google how to do something in Max the only halfway decent quality instructions are part of a paid tutorial.  One one of the main reasons I switched from Max to Blender.  Also, this isn't the place to be arguing about this.  If you want to complain about Blender's UI go to reddit or blenderartists.

Answer (score 9):

If you need all the fonts to be loaded automatically this can be done with a script ( or an addon ) :

1. first you have to set the fonts directory in blender user preferences.

[image]

2. install the addon and enable it ( or run load_fonts() when you need it ).

---

```
import os
import bpy

def load_fonts():
    font_dir = bpy.context.user_preferences.filepaths.font_directory
    for file in os.listdir(font_dir):
        if file.endswith(".ttf"):  
           bpy.data.fonts.load(font_dir+file)
```

[script as an addon](https://github.com/chebhou/Load-font)

Comment: Script snippet still works with 2.83.

Answer (score 2):

You can load Opentype and TrueType fonts in Blender. Blender does not load in font families into the separate slots (Regular, Bold, Italic, etc), you have to do that manually.

On OSX, sometimes font files are contained in packages called a "font suitcase". Blender does not load these either.

If your fonts are PostScript fonts, there are many tools online line to convert them to OpenType.

Comment: Glad to hear this. I have MANY OpenType fonts. Typography is not mentioned in the Ref Manual at all. I have not been able to find access to font list anywhere in Blender. I still need to know HOW to do this. WHERE is font access located in Blender?

Answer (score 2):

I've updated Chebhou's excellent reply for Blender 2.80+.

Simply run the following in the Scripting console:

```
import os
import bpy

font_dir = bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.font_directory
for file in os.listdir(font_dir):
    if file.endswith(".ttf"):  
        bpy.data.fonts.load(font_dir+file)
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a [tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTk6oMvP1eU), As a long-time designer but Blender noob, I'm spoiled by font management software on Mac (FontAgentPro). Since Blender doesn't have system-level font access, I need to :

1. Set some text in Blender.
2. Use FontAgentPro to find the font I want.
3. Locate fonts on the system drive.
4. Manually load each one into Blender on a per-project basis.

It's tedious, but at least now I know it's possible!  :+)