# Can't see any fonts except Bfont for text objects

Tags: text-object

When I go to object data properties tab on the text object in properties editor the only font I see is Bfont. In blender preferences the windows font folder seems to be correctly configured and points towards C:\WINDOWS\Fonts. Why am I not seeing any fonts except Bfont? Blender version 2.82.7. Do I need to manually install the fonts for blender?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/how-to-change-font-for-text-objects?rq=1

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/69255/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new font can be loaded by clicking on the folder icon in the *Font* panel.

[image: Font Object Data Properties]

Blender will open the directory configured in *Preferences > File Paths* by default. All font files located in the directory will be displayed. If you've installed fonts through the *Install* option, instead of *Install for all users*, they will not be located in `C:\Windows\Fonts` but `C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts` instead.

[image: Font install options]
<sub>Image source: [Announcing Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 17704](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/06/27/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17704/)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty annoying way for blender to do it. What for is the big F button there for?

Comment: @user79164 That's for choosing fonts that have already been loaded.